# Dismiss "Confirm Navigation" popup with Watir

Tags: javascript, popup, watir, watir-webdriver, onbeforeunload

I am trying to dismiss "Confirm Navigation" popup. This is how it looks like in Chrome.

[image]

To see the popup:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://www.gravityforms.com/demo/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gf_new_form"
browser.text_field(:id => "user_login").set "demo"
browser.text_field(:id => "user_pass").set "demo"
browser.button(:id => "wp-submit").click
browser.refresh
```

At the moment I override `onbeforeunload` when I visit the page, as suggested at http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/

```
browser.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};")
```

So, the script now looks like this:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "http://www.gravityforms.com/demo/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gf_new_form"
browser.text_field(:id => "user_login").set "demo"
browser.text_field(:id => "user_pass").set "demo"
browser.button(:id => "wp-submit").click
browser.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};")
browser.refresh
```

And it works just fine. I am just wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that's the best way for now.

I filed a [bug/feature-request](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/109) for this about two months back.  You might want to comment there and add a vote of support if it's something that would make things easier for you.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, added my comment there.