# How to handle windows pop up in IE using Ruby

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, watir-classic

Please help me how to handle this pop ups.
 [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dismiss "Confirm Navigation" popup with Watir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389379/dismiss-confirm-navigation-popup-with-watir)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, I tried with your code but it is not working in IE browser.

Comment: There's an [`Alert`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Alert) class that might do the trick (e.g. `browser.alert.ok`).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your last question, I assume you are using Watir-Classic (even though you have also listed Watir-Webdriver).

As @orde mentioned in the comments, Watir has an `Alert` class for handling these types of dialogs. Unfortunately, in terms of clicking buttons, Watir-Classic only has an [`#ok` method defined](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/blob/master/lib/watir-classic/dialogs/alert.rb#L36-L39):

```
# Press the "OK" button on the JavaScript dialog.
def ok
  dialog.button(:value => "OK").click
  wait_until_not_exists
end
```

This will not work for this dialog as there is a "Yes" and "No" button rather than an "OK" button. You will need to duplicate this functionality with the right value.

Note that the `dialog` is a RAutomation window and no longer Watir specific code. As a result, the button values are not always intuitive - it is not always just the text you see. To get the right values, you should ask the dialog what values it sees:

```
browser.alert.send(:dialog).buttons.map(&:value)
#=> ["&Yes", "&No"]
```

We can then make the same calls as the `#ok` method, but with the correct value:

```
alert = browser.alert
alert.send(:dialog).button(:value => '&Yes').click
alert.wait_while_present
```

Comment: I tried with: save_dialog = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
        save_dialog.ControlClick("Windows Internet Explorer", "Yes", "[CLASS:Button;INSTANCE:1]") this code it is working fine.

Comment: @JustinKo Such an excellent way to handle this error. But why do you need to call a private method `dialog` through `send` method. We can include the generic method in the class `Alert` like `def click value
      dialog.buton(:value=>value).click
      wait_until_not_exists   
    end` What do you say?

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine to handle this type of pop ups:

```
save_dialog = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control") save_dialog.ControlClick("Windows Internet Explorer", "Yes", "[CLASS:Button;INSTANCE:1]")
```